# C++ Get file location of process without elevated rights

Tags: c++, winapi, location

I'd like to know how you can find the full location of a process without having elevated rights. I tried doing it with the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, but it requires admin privileges. Its very easy to do in C# without elevated rights, but I can't seem to find the solution in C++. Any help?

Comment: How are you doing it in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QueryFullProcessImageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only requires `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` rights, which doesn't need admin privileges.

Comment: Thank you! I had already tried this, but then it "didn't work". I kept checking the return value of GetLastError, but I forgot to reset it with the SetLastError.. Turns out it might have already been working

Comment: GetLastError only gives a meaningful value if the previous API failed.  Resetting it with SetLastError is not reliable because the API function may change the error value even if the function doesn't fail.  In other words, you should only call GetLastError if QueryFullProcessImageName returns FALSE.